# How to limit random.choice() to 1 per x seconds?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to programming and I need a way to limit the randomization of the variable food_choice so it doesn't print tons of images on my pygame screen.

Here is a section of my code. I believe the problem is because my function draw_food() is inside of the main loop, meaning that everytime the game runs with the determined tick, the function draw_food() is then run again, picking another food, causing an endless randomization. I need to way to limit this randomization to once per x seconds.

````
def draw_food():

    food_choice = random.choice(food_types)

    for object in object_list[:]:
        screen.blit(food_choice, (foodx, foody))
        object.deter -= 0.035

        if object.deter < 1: 
            object_list.remove(object)

def draw_game_window():
    
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    draw_food()

    cat.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update()


# main loop
cat = player(200, 355, 67, 65)
run = True 

object_list = []
time_interval = 5000 # 200 milliseconds == 0.2 seconds
next_object_time = 0

while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    
    draw_game_window()

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    if current_time > next_object_time:
        next_object_time += time_interval
        object_list.append(Object())

pygame.quit()```
````

Comment: Hey man, could you please limit the code to just the part relevant to the question? It's a pain to figure out what's going on otherwise, and it's probably why someone downvoted you.

Comment: @Arkleseisure done, sorry I'm new here, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `randomizeFood` event every second like this.

```
randomizeFood = pygame.USEREVENT + 0
pygame.time.set_timer(randomizeFood, 1000) #time in ms
```

Then in your event loop, create random food when this event is generated.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == randomizeFood:
            food_choice = random.choice(food_types)
```

Answer (score 1):

Eiter use a timer event as already explained in an answer, or use [`pygame.time.get_ticks`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html). This function returns the number of milliseconds since the application was started.
Use global variables to store the time and the food. You have to use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt) to change a global variable within a function

```py
food_choice = None
next_choice_time = 0

def draw_food():

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if current_time >= next_choice_time:
        next_choice_time = current_time + 1000 # in 1 second (1000 millisecodns)

        food_choice = random.choice(food_types)
```